# How to configure Spring 3.0 annotations based xml file?

Tags: spring

I'm new to Spring, and searching how to configure it's XML file so all beans will be created by container? And how I can tell in application to load this file on server start-up?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sample available at https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/. Look at the web.xml and the spring config in .../WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the servlet in web.xml in following way for Spring.

```
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

also you need to create the xml file called **dispatcher-servlet.xml** where you can specify the beans you would like the Spring Framework to create for you.

Hope that helps you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a Spring MVC application, follow the indication @Japan Trivedi gave you.
If case you're working on a standalone Spring application, here's an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="package.containing.your.bean.classes" />
</beans>
```

Suppose this configuration file is named "spring-config.xml"
Simply put this file in the classpath of your application and in the code, initialize the Spring application context like this :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
```

Then, from the context object, you'll be able to retrieve the beans, which have been automatically instantiated by Spring.

Note that this solution does not fully applied IOC concept as you actually explicitly when and what bean you retrieve.